# Are users commonly implemented as Roles with the ability to login?

Tags: security, postgresql, roles, rbac

In recent versions of PostgreSQL [users are implemented as roles that can login](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createuser.html). Is this common in an RBAC implementations, that a user is just another role with the ability to login (or similar)? Some of what I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509424/good-resources-for-writing-a-authentication-authorization-system) so far doesn't suggest that... but maybe I've misread or just not read the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

In particular what i understand in your question is the differences and relation between RBAC and create user command in postgresql, As you may know PostgreSQL manages database access permissions using the concept of roles. This role can be  database user, or a group of database users, depending on how the role is set up.

As referred [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createrole.html) Roles can own database objects (for example, tables) and can assign privileges on those objects to other roles to control who has access to which objects.

Furthermore, it is emphasized that CREATE USER is  an alias for CREATE ROLE, which see for more information. The only difference is that when the command is spelled CREATE USER, LOGIN is assumed by default, whereas NOLOGIN is assumed when the command is spelled CREATE ROLE. (mentioned in postgresql manuel)

The concept of roles subsumes the concepts of "users" and "groups". In PostgreSQL versions before 8.1, users and groups were distinct kinds of entities, but now there are only roles. Any role can act as a user, a group, or both.

And RBAC is a access control, there can be a relation with databases however it is used for any kind of "stuff" access in an PC or large networks similar to other access control (MAC DAC), A database management system, in its access control mechanism, can also apply other access control mechanisms. In this case, the objects are tables, views, procedures, etc. You can read details from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control)

**Finally, All relational DBMS provide some sort of intrinsic security mechanisms designed to minimize threats. If it fits for your database application you can benefit from CREATE USER or CREATE ROLE commands to reduce security risk, that's why these commands exists.**

Comment: I'm not really asking about postgres... this is more of an RBAC question, I'm asking if it's common for RBAC systems to be implemented as Postgres is. I understand how Postgres works, and I have a basic understanding of an RBAC system (over MAC DAC) but it doesn't seem like in the descriptions I've read of RBAC that Postgres has implemented it in the typical way (not saying that's wrong).

Comment: RBAC is general access control policy that can be used if it fits your design, esp. can be used in Os level. In databases, there are similar efforts to reduce the security risk. You can go over details of RBAC to have more idea of your question. thanks.